# Resize HDF5 dataset in Julia

Tags: julia, hdf5

Is there a way to resize a chunked dataset in HDF5 using Julia's HDF5.jl?  I didn't see anything in the documentation.  Looking through the source, all I found was `set_dims!()`, but that cannot extend a dataset (only shrink it).  Does HDF5.jl have the ability to enlarge an existing (chunked) dataset?  This is a very important feature for me, and I would rather not have to call into another language.

Comment: I see that my question has been downvoted.  I suspect that means I'm in violation of some community guideline, but if I knew what then I probably wouldn't have violated that guideline.  If someone would let me know what's wrong with my question, I will be happy to modify it to be more appropriate.

Comment: This is an excellent example of why down-voters should *always* at least consider adding a comment explaining the down-vote (or upvote an existing explanation comment). The question looks sensible to me, I'll upvote you back to zero. My best guess is the down-voter's rationale was a variant on "what have you tried"? However, the fact you have read the docs and referenced `set_dims!()` is more than enough to satisfy me that you have attempted to answer your own question before posting.

Comment: Also, in response to the question: Do you know which function from the HDF5 library does what you need? @tholy wrapped most of the commonly used functions in that library in the HDF5.jl package, but not all of them are exported (or documented), ie you would need to use `HDF5.FunctionName` to call them. If the function you want has not been wrapped then you could try submitting a pull request, although be prepared that the response may be "no free time at the moment, please try implementing the wrapper yourself".

Comment: For a variety of reasons, I'm working on adapting a C++ code to Julia.  The C++ method that does this is Dataset::extend.

Comment: There is a [`H5Dset_extent`](http://www.hdfgroup.org/HDF5/doc/RM/RM_H5D.html#Dataset-SetExtent) function. As @colin has suggested how about trying `HDF5.h5d_set_extent()`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The docs have a brief mention of extendible dimensions in `hdf5.md` excerpted below.

You can use extendible dimensions,

```
d = d_create(parent, name, dtype, (dims, max_dims), "chunk", (chunk_dims), [lcpl, dcpl, dapl])
set_dims!(d, new_dims)
```

where dims is a tuple of integers. For example

```
b = d_create(fid, "b", Int, ((1000,),(-1,)), "chunk", (100,)) #-1 is equivalent to typemax(Hsize)
set_dims!(b, (10000,))
b[1:10000] = [1:10000]
```

Answer (score 2):

I believe I've got it figured out.  The issue is that I forgot to give the dataspace a large enough max_dims.  Doing that required digging into the lower-level API.  The solution I found was:

```
dspace = HDF5.dataspace((6,20)::Dims, max_dims=(6,typemax(Int64)))
dtype = HDF5.datatype(Float64)
dset = HDF5.d_create(prt, "trajectory", dtype, dspace, "chunk", (6,10))
```

Once I created a dataset that can be resized appropriately, the `set_dims!` function resizes the dataset correctly.

I think I located a few minor issues with the API, which I had to work around or change in my local version.  I will get in touch with the HDF5.jl owner regarding those.  For those interested:

- The constant `H5S_UNLIMITED` is of type `Uint64`, but the `dataspace` function will only accept tuples of `Int64`, hence why I used `typemax(Int64)` for my `max_dims` to imitate how `H5S_UNLIMITED` is derived.
- The form of `d_create` which I used calls `h5d_create` incorrectly; it passes `parent` instead of `checkvalid(parent).id` (can be seen by comparison with other forms of `d_create`).